# EF Core 6: how to define global query filters based on current user role?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to know if is it possibile to create global query filters on my entities in my `ApplicationDbContext` based on the current user role.

I have created a `IdentityService` which I use to get the current User informations (Id, Role ecc...).

```cs
public class IdentityService { 

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
        
    public IdentityService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        => this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    
    public string GetUserId()
        => httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.GetId();
    
    public string GetUserRole()
        => httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.GetRole();

    public string GetUserRoleId()
        => httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.GetUserRoleId();

    public string GetUserIpAddress()
        => httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

    public int? GetUserThemeColor()
            => httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.GetThemeColor();
}
```

I have injected it in my `ApplicationDbContext` through the constructor:

```cs
public ApplicationDbContext(
    DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, 
    IdentityService identityService): base(options) 
        => this.identityService = identityService;
```

So now I know that I can easily obtain my current user role.

I have an entity named `Intervention` configured in the method `OnModelCreating()` like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Intervention>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("Interventions");

        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
            .HasName("PK__Intervention");

        //Properties mapping...
        //...
        //...


        string userRole = identityService.GetUserRole();
        string userRoleId = identityService.GetUserRoleId();

        switch (userRole)
        {
            case "Master":
                break;
            default://Customer
                entity = entity.HasQueryFilter(e => e.CustomerId.Equals(userRoleId));
                break;
        }
        
    });
```

The query filter defined in the switch doesn't work as expected since the `OnModelCreating()` is called without a HttpContext (it is null right here!!), so I don't have a user role. It is possibile to do something like this that actually works? I would like to filter my entity **in different ways** automatically at runtime, based on the current user role...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change query filter on the fly. It is defined once per `DbContext` descendant. But you can create a filter which handles all possible combinations.

Define properties in your `DbContext`. Using of local variables is not allowed in query filter.

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext
{
    ...

    public string UserRole => identityService.GetUserRole(); 
    public string UserRoleId => identityService.GetUserRoleId(); 
}
```

And define common query filter:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Intervention>(entity =>
    {
        entity = entity.HasQueryFilter(e => UserRole == "Master" || e.CustomerId.Equals(UserRoleId)));
    });
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! I would like to use the switch statement since, typically, our applications have more than 2 defined roles, so the single common filter would be really "ugly"....

Comment: You can't use switch, it is not supported by Expression Tree. You have to use *ugly* filter.