# Restricting sql queries to currently logged in user

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, microsoft-identity-platform

My tech stack is ASP.NET Core with Azure AD (B2C) authentication. I am using EF Core with Azure SQL to store data. I have a table with data from multiple users, e.g. orders from an online shop, where each order belongs to one user. Now I want to get all orders for the logged in user. Would I just write my query like (dummy code)

```
Orders.Where(row => row.UserId == loggedInUserId)
```

or is there some mechanism in ASP.NET Core (or maybe Microsoft Identity Platform), that automatically restricts the query to the currently logged in user?

Comment: Thanks to EF Core team, there is no hidden behavior in this case. You have to make filter by yourself. Or define Global Query filter as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74052506/10646316)

Comment: ah, that looks very interesting. Please post as answer :-) Btw what if I have tables that don't contain a user id and most do? Can that be handled?

Comment: Query filter can use navigation properties and you can access to other tables for filtering. I don't think it is goo idea to make another similar answer if there is no special differences.